# Cannot find symbol a and b when rotating matrix

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

This is a code to rotate matrix clockwise and anticlockwise by `k` elements I am getting error cannot find symbol when I run this code. If I run this individually I noticed one more bug that it is not able to rotate anticlockwise for elements more than 3×3 whether I increase `M` or `N` it is not able to do anticlockwise rotation.

## Main

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int R=sc.nextInt();
        int C=sc.nextInt();
        int matrix[][]=new int[R][C];
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<C;j++){
            if(sc.hasNext()){
                int a=sc.nextInt();
                matrix[i][j]=a;
        }
        }
        }
        int rot=sc.nextInt();
        int matrix2[][]=matrix.clone();
        sc.close();
        Anti a=new Anti();
        a.rotatematrix(R, C, matrix,rot);
        clock c=new clock();
        c.antirotatematrix(R,C,matrix2,rot);
    }
}
```

## class Anti

```
class Anti{
    public void antirotatematrix(int m, 
                    int n, int mat[][],int rot) 
    { 
        int row = 0, col = n-1; 
        int prev, curr; 
        System.out.println("Anticlockwise Rotation");
        for( int a=0;a<rot;a++)
    {    while (row < m && col < n ) 
        { 
            if (row+1 == m || col  == 0) {
                break; }
            prev = mat[row + 1][col]; 
            for (int i = col; i>= 0; i--) 
            { 
                curr = mat[row][i]; 
                mat[row][i] = prev; 
                prev = curr; 
            } 
            row++; 

            for (int i = row; i < m; i++) 
            {  
                curr = mat[i][0]; 
                mat[i][0] = prev; 
                prev = curr; 
            }
            n--; 

            if (row < m) {
                for (int i = n-2; i <= col; i++) 
                { 
                    curr = mat[m-1][i]; 
                    mat[m-1][i] = prev; 
                    prev = curr; 
                } 
            } 
            m--;  
            if (col <= n) 
            { 
                for (int i = m-1; i >= row; i--) 
                { 
                    curr = mat[i][col]; 
                    mat[i][col] = prev; 
                    prev = curr; 
                } 
            } 
            col++; 
        }
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++) {
            { 
                for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++) 
                System.out.print( mat[i][j] + " "); 
                System.out.print("\n"); 
            } 
    } 
    }
}
```

## class Clock

```
class clock{
    public void rotatematrix(int m, 
                    int n, int mat[][],int rot) 
    { 
        int row = 0, col = 0; 
        int prev, curr; 
        int matri[][]=new int[m][n];
        System.out.println("Clockwise Rotation");
        for(int b=0;b<rot;b++){
        while (row < m && col < n) 
        { 
            if (row + 1 == m || col + 1 == n) 
                break; 
            prev = mat[row + 1][col]; 
            for (int i = col; i < n; i++) 
            { 
                curr = mat[row][i]; 
                mat[row][i] = prev; 
                prev = curr; 
            } 
            row++; 
            for (int i = row; i < m; i++) 
            { 
                curr = mat[i][n-1]; 
                mat[i][n-1] = prev; 
                prev = curr; 
            } 
            n--; 
            if (row < m) 
            { 
                for (int i = n-1; i >= col; i--) 
                { 
                    curr = mat[m-1][i]; 
                    mat[m-1][i] = prev; 
                    prev = curr; 
                } 
            } 
            m--;
            if (col < n) 
            { 
                for (int i = m-1; i >= row; i--) 
                { 
                    curr = mat[i][col]; 
                    mat[i][col] = prev; 
                    prev = curr; 
                } 
            } 
            col++; 
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++) {
            { 
                for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++) 
                System.out.print( mat[i][j] + " "); 
                System.out.print("\n"); 
            } 
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I am getting error cannot find symbol when I run this code.*" - You mean when you compile the code? Please include the complete compiler error.

Comment: Where are the symbols a, b?

Comment: Your real problem: you write unreadable code. Start by giving **meaningful** names to your variables. You probably think "I save by using 1-char names". No, you don't. Because the 3 seconds you spent less on typing ... each time you try to make sense out of this, you spend minutes more. So: research "clean code", and focus on that part, too. There is a certain chance: if you would write human readable code, you would be able to fix compiler errors yourself much quicker ... and you wouldnt need other people to tell you what is wrong in your own code ...

Comment: @Turing85  Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                 a.rotatematrix(R, C, matrix,rot);
                  ^
                symbol:   method rotatematrix(int,int,int[][],int)
                location: variable a of type Anti
Main.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        c.antirotatematrix(R,C,matrix2,rot);
         ^
  symbol:   method antirotatematrix(int,int,int[][],int)
  location: variable c of type clock
2 errors